# Having Error 3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." after a while on the application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

> I'm having the error 3840 "JSON text did not start with array or
>   object and option to allow fragments not set." on my application after
>   being on the same page for a while.

I'm calling a cloud code function from my Parse server, getting the answer and displaying it. It works fine, but after waiting a little bit the application crashes.

I'm calling my manager for the cloud code function:

```
ParseManager.sharedManager().fetchPrice(startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate, housingId: housing.objectId!) { (objects, error) in
    if (objects != []) {
        var price = 0

     for object in objects! {
         price += object["prix"] as! Int
     }
     price /= objects!.count
     self.priceByNight.text = "Price: \(price)"
    }
}
```

In my manager:

```
func fetchPrice(startDate: Date, endDate: Date, housingId: String, completion: PFResults?) {
 let params = [
    "startDate": startDate,
    "endDate": endDate,
    "housing": housingId
 ] as [String : Any]

 PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "fetchPrice", withParameters: params) { (objects, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
        completion?(nil, error)
        return
    }

    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
        completion?(objects, nil)
    }
 }
}
```

This is what my function send me back:

```
{
    "result": [{
        "price": 10,
        "createdAt": "2019-05-07T12:39:47.320Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-05-09T15:31:25.957Z",
        "date": {
            "__type": "Date",
            "iso": "2019-05-20T12:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "idHousing": {
            "__type": "Relation",
            "className": "myOtherClassName"
        },
        "objectId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
        "__type": "Object",
        "className": "MyClassName"
    }]
}
```

Comment: post your expected response json

Comment: @Sh_Khan Just edited my post

Comment: Does  `...` inside the json or you mean more ?

Comment: It means there is more

Comment: You've said the JSON is what your function is returning. It looks valid, are you certain thats what you are getting or thats what you *think* you are getting. I've never used parse, I don't know if its possible to get the raw http response and see whats inside, if not you couldn't connect your simulator to charles proxy and see exactly what you are getting from Parse. I suspect you are not getting that back

Comment: I can see the data and use it in my view, the error only occurs after some time.

Comment: Do you know which line of code is throwing the error?

Comment: It's this one: `for object in objects! {`  maybe my if doesn't have the right condition just before.

Comment: That was it, I changed `if (objects != []) {` to `if let objs = objects {` and it works now.

Comment: Congratulations on figuring it out. You should post your answer and accept it so others know what the error was. (not everyone reads all the comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was how I was checking what the manager was returning, checking it the wrong way made it try to do things with a null object.

The solution was to change `if (objects != []) {` to `if let objs = objects {` and it works now.